# Custom attributes in Saml2AuthnRequest and Saml2AuthnResponse using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 library

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are using `itfoxtec-identity-saml2` library to integrate saml in our .Net web API application.
We are passing a couple of custom attributes in relayState (ex. returnUrl, redirectionParams etc.) to make use of them once we get the relayState back from SP.

One of the service providers is not able to return relayState with multiple parameters because of the "&" separator.
Is it possible to include these custom attributes in Saml2AuthnRequest object and get the same attributes back in Saml2AuthnResponse or is relayState the only way to send and receive the custom dynamic parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to include these custom attributes in Saml2AuthnRequest object and get the same attributes back in Saml2AuthnResponse

A SAML2 authentication request can contain various *custom* extensions to carry extra data, flags, etc. However, anything that you would include in there would be *custom*, and the service provider implementation must be able to support and recognize it. It's completely non-standard and would not scale.

> is relayState the only way to send and receive the custom dynamic parameters?

Yes, it is. You might want to encode the final value in such a way that could be included in the relay-state parameter as a single value.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense.

Comment: I am also having difficulties in reading the additional <Attributes/> from metadata url... Is there a property or something that would parse the Attributes in metadata and provide a collection? I am getting attributes similar to <Attribute xmlns="..." Name="abc" NameFormat="..." FriendlyName="abc"/> inside IDPSSODescriptor element